# Getting error "there is no row at position 0"

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

please help me out to sort out this... I'm getting error as "there is no row at position 0", "index out of range exception was unhanded by user code"

Below is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MTMSService obj = new MTMSService();
    DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
    {
        MTMSDTO objc = new MTMSDTO();
        {
            objc.TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["TaskID"]);
            DataSet rep = obj.GetReports(objc);
            DataView Rprts = new DataView();
            Rprts.Table = rep.Tables[0];

            LblTaskID.Text = rep.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TaskID"].ToString();
            LblTaskName.Text = rep.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TaskName"].ToString();
            LblDueDate.Text = rep.Tables[2].Rows[0]["DueDate"].ToString();
            LblDescription.Text = rep.Tables[3].Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
            LblAssignBy.Text = rep.Tables[4].Rows[0]["AssignBy"].ToString();
            LblStatus.Text = rep.Tables[5].Rows[0]["Status"].ToString();
            LblPercentageComplete.Text = 
                    rep.Tables[6].Rows[0]["PercentageComplete"].ToString();

            LblTaskName.Visible = true;
            LblAssignBy.Visible = true;
            LblDescription.Visible = true;
            LblDueDate.Visible = true;
            LblStatus.Visible = true;
            LblPercentageComplete.Visible = true;
            LblAssignTo.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the message is pretty clear, isn't it? What is it you don't understand? If `rep.Tables[0]` doesn't contain any rows, then accessing `Rows[0]` throws an exception.

Comment: Check to see if there are any rows in the table before trying to use it!

Comment: **Debug** and **Watch**

Comment: Also take a look at the indexes used to access the tables collection, I doubt you have 7 tables in that dataset

Comment: evn if i make it as rep.tables[1] its swin d same error

Comment: shuld i use count aywer ?

Comment: can i plz get the code ... im a newbie.. findin it difficult wat u ppl r tryn to say

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not checking if your tables have any content. The message is clear: There is no row at position 0.

The exception is probably being thrown on this line, or one following it:

```
LblTaskID.Text = rep.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TaskID"].ToString();
```

You should verify that rows exist before attempting to get data from them. Something like the following:

```
var table = rep.Tables[0];
if (table.Rows.Count > 0){
    // Fetch the data... 
}
else
{
    // Handle missing data in an appropriate way...
}
```

Comment: this worked fine... thanks... but my grid view row data isnt displaying in anoher page.. getting only empty labels

Answer (score 4):

***The earlier advice is all good and you should follow it.***

However it looks obvious to me that the reason there is no row at position 0 is that you are looking at the wrong table.  I seriously doubt you have id in one table, name in another, etc., but you are indexing to a different table for each piece of data.

```
rep.Tables[1]
rep.Tables[2]
rep.Tables[3]
rep.Tables[4]
rep.Tables[5]
rep.Tables[6]
```

should all be

```
rep.Tables[0]
```

You surely only have one table, but are looking at table 0 through table 6!

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing anything always check for items first. After you do that and if this still occurs check the column names are they exact? For example is `"TaskID"` really `"TaskId"` and that indexing is failing? Finally are these items nullable? If so calling a ToString() on a null field is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

check that your datatable is empty