# IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code: There is no row at position 0

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, api

```
CardDetails Top_Exixts_Card = new CardDetails();
DataSet Top_up_Dataset = new DataSet();

Top_Exixts_Card.CardId = Convert.ToInt32(Top_up_Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
Top_Exixts_Card.AccountNo = Top_up_Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][1] + "";
```

above mentioned are write in model class.

my apicontroller

```
Sub_card_details = new Modelclass().Modelclassname(cardsubscribers);
```

how to solve this error in model class.

Comment: It's resolved by having data in row at position 0

Comment: dont understand,please explain briefly

Comment: fdsfsdf= new model().modelclassname(Convert.ToInt32(variablename.AccountNo));

            asdasds= new model().model classname(fdsfsdf);

Comment: before fetching data from dataset set a condition to check if dataset has value or not?

Comment: Dataset having a value

Comment: but as per your error says there is no row at position 0, which indicate that there is no data in your dataset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error "there is no row at position 0"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343274/getting-error-there-is-no-row-at-position-0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that there is actually data there otherwise you will get indexing errors.

Based on your example there is potential to get errors on `Table` and `Rows` if you try to index them and they are empty. You should also check for nulls as I am not certain that the `Tables` property of `DataSet` initializes to a non null value value when you initialize `DataSet`

```
CardDetails Top_Exixts_Card = new CardDetails();
DataSet Top_up_Dataset = new DataSet();

if(Top_up_Dataset.Tables != null) {
    if(Top_up_Dataset.Tables.Count > 0 && Top_up_Dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) {
        Top_Exixts_Card.CardId = Convert.ToInt32(Top_up_Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
        Top_Exixts_Card.AccountNo = Top_up_Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][1] + "";
    }
}
```